# Computer has good specs, yet running applications slowly?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, performance, motherboard

I don't know what's up with my pc it's running pretty slow, and it was like this when I bought it too. It just runs applications like google chrome skype,games pretty slowly when my old pc of 2gb ram runs applications pretty fast. I would like to know what I could upgrade or do to make it run things faster. Any help is appreciated.

These are my pc's specs:

CPU : FX-6300 Six Core 
GPU : Radeon HD 7770 1GB GDDR5 
 
RAM : 8 GB DDR3 1600MHz 
OS Hard Drive : Seagate ST500DM002-1BD142 500GB 
 
Motherboard : Asus M5A78L-M/USB3 
Operating System : Win 7 64

Comment: It'd help to know where your computer is failing to perform. Tools like Process Hacker (http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) are a quick way to monitor your CPU, RAM, GPU ect to see whats running too high.

Comment: Open the task manager and see if your CPU, RAM or HDD is maxed out all the time. If it is, upgrade that part. Also, scan your PC for viruses and malware.

Comment: Many program can be run in backround which need a memory or use your processor. Please first check which program runs in your PC or share this list.

Comment: I downloaded it, now how do i see where my pc is failing to perform?

Comment: My CPU usage is barely maxed out (usually 0%-20).. and memory is around 2 gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowest thing on most modern PCs are either the Network Interface or the Hard Disk. Upgrading to a SSD can do wonders for speeding up a PC. Without more information, this is about as much advice as I can give.

Comment: My hard disk is bad i heard, this might be it. Do you know where I can get a rather cheap good SSD card?

Comment: tigerdirect, newegg, or ebay might be some first stops.

Comment: Amazon... I just installed a second 240 GB Intel SSD that cost about $160.